# How to follow and seek in a file being piped through a filter, in less

Tags: sed, tail, less

I basically wish to seek, search and follow a growing log file *after passing it through a `sed` filter*. I figured I need to follow a file with `tail -f` pipe it to `sed` and then pipe that to `less`. For testing, I first tried combining `tail -f` and `less +F` to no avail:

- `tail -f file | less +F` -- less doesn't run before one presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop tail's following. `less` options `-B -b 1` do not help.
- `less +F -f <(tail -f file)` exhibits the same behavior.

If anyone knows a better/simpler solution than what I figured out in the end, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Seems related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33018/have-bash-script-wait-for-status-message-before-continuing

Comment: You would need a [seekable pipe](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30885/is-it-possible-to-make-seek-operations-on-a-named-pipe-return-successful), but there's no such facility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since piping directly didn't work, I tried connecting `tail -f`, `sed` and `less +F` via a temporary file. Ended up with the following

```
function lessx {
    [ -f "$1" ] || { echo "First argument must be a file"; return 1; }
    local tmpfile=$(mktemp /tmp/"$(basename "$1.XXX")")
    [ -f "$tmpfile" ] || { echo '`mktemp` failed'; return 1; }
    tail -f "$1" | stdbuf -i0 -o0 sed 's:\\\?\\n:\n:g' > "$tmpfile" &
    less +F "$tmpfile"
    kill %% # kill the tail pipeline, after less exits
    rm "$tmpfile"
}
```

which does the job, though it's more complicated than I'd like. Note that my SunOS `tail` doesn't understand `--pid`, so I manually kill the `tail` pipeline.