# continuous reading from named pipe (cat or tail -f)

Tags: pipe, cat, tail, fifo

I have configured `rsyslog` to log certain log events to `/dev/xconsole`:

```
*.*;cron.!=info;mail.!=info      |/dev/xconsole
```

`/dev/xconsole` is a named pipe (`fifo`). If I want to see what is being logged, I can do `cat /dev/xconsole`. I am surprised to see, that the command `cat /dev/xconsole` does not finish after reading the file, but instead acts as `tail -f`. in other words, the two commands behave the same:

```
cat /dev/xconsole
tail -f /dev/xconsole
```

Can somebody please explain why is that?

Is there any difference between the two?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`cat` keeps reading until it gets EOF. A pipe produces EOF on the output only when it gets EOF on the input. The logging daemon is opening the file, writing to it, **and keeping it open** — just like it does for a regular file — so EOF is never generated on the output. `cat` just keeps reading, blocking whenever it exhausts what's currently in the pipe.

You can try this out yourself manually:

```
$ mkfifo test
$ cat test
```

And in another terminal:

```
$ cat > test
hello
```

There will be output in the other terminal. Then enter:

```
world
```

There will be *more* output in the other terminal. If you now Ctrl-D the input then the other `cat` will terminate too.

In this case, the only observable difference between `cat` and `tail -f` will be if the logging daemon is terminated or restarted: `cat` will stop permanently when the write end of the pipe is closed, but `tail -f` will keep going (reopening the file) when the daemon is restarted.

Comment: sorry I don't see where "world" will come from in your example :)

Comment: From your typing it in.

Comment: And then you type `world`, and, lo, "world" appears in the other terminal.

Comment: "but `tail -f` will keep going..."  Is it because contrary to `cat`, `tail -f` will ignore EOF conditions and will only stop permanently when one enters `Ctrl`+`C` (i.e. when receiving an interrupt signal)?

Answer (score 3):

There is also a difference in **buffering** between `cat` and `tail -f`. You can check this out:

Create pipe: `mkfifo pipe`

Start reading pipe using `cat` in background: `cat pipe &`

Open pipe and write to it every second: `perl -MFcntl -we 'sysopen(my $fh, "pipe", O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCK); while() {warn "written: " . syswrite($fh, "hello\n"); sleep 1}'`

Now try this with `tail -f pipe &` instead of `cat`. So you can see that `cat` prints lines as soon as they are written to pipe by perl script, while `tail -f`  buffers them up to 4kb before printing to stdout.

Answer (score -4):

`cat` shows you the whole file when `tail -f` Shows only the last rows and follows. So if the file is short they behave the same, but if the file is big (100+ rows) you can see a clear difference between them two.

Additional information about those commands :

`tail` http://www.computerhope.com/unix/utail.htm

`cat` http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucat.htm