# Linux FIFO buffering depends on invocation order of readers and writers

Tags: linux, pipe, tail, fifo, buffer

I'm trying to write a simple python script that reads from a fifo and then writes to another fifo.

I have created two FIFOs using the following command:

```bsh
$ mkfifo input
$ mkfifo output
```

I invoke the script using the following command:

```bsh
$ tail -f input | stdbuf -oL ../entropyCalc/entropy.py > output
```

, observe the FIFO `output` using:

```bsh
$ tail -f output
```

and then invoke a writer using the following command:

```bsh
$ echo "/path/to/a/valid/file" >> input
```

The problem is I expect the fifo to output the result as soon as it processes the input file, but I only observe that when I invoke (execute) the script once, exit and then re-execute the script. Everything works fine after this.

In summary:
I don't see any output in the reader if I execute script -> spin up reader -> write to `input` fifo
But, the command `tail -f output` outputs the result when I execute the script -> spin up the reader -> write to fifo -> kill script -> re-execute the script

I'm not sure what causes this behaviour since I'd expect the system to write to the files as soon as the result is written to stdout. I'd have expected the buffering if I would not used `stdbuf -oL` which limits buffering to a line.

The python script is a simple entropy calculator:

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python2

import sys, os
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import entropy

while 1:
    try:
        line = sys.stdin.readline()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

    if not line:
        break

    line = line.strip()

    if not line == '':
        fname1 = open(line)
        fsize = os.path.getsize(line)
        f1 = np.frombuffer(fname1.read(fsize), dtype=np.uint8)
        value,counts = np.unique(f1, return_counts=True)
        print line,str(entropy(counts))
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

I'm using bash 4.4 on Ubuntu 18.04.3

Comment: You have unbuffered the script but not tail. Why not? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/423645/70524

Comment: That doesn't work if I use `tail -f` as the reader, but it does if I use `cat output`, any reason why it behaves this way?

Comment: your Q is way to deep for me, but you please explain the purpose of `tail -f fifo | command ..` in your 2nd codeblock? why not just `<fifo command ..`?

Answer (score 0):

You used `tail` incorrectly.

What you observed is simply an indication that **`tail -f output` works as advertised**. And there are more pitfalls in your `tail -f input` usage.

Please note that these `tail` misuses will also break the operational integrity of your script. See below for details...

#### Short Explanation

Problems with your `tail -f input` usage:

- It waits for end-of-file at first.
- Once end-of-file is *first* reached (first filename-giver terminated), it would only pass last 10 filenames to the script; breaking operational integrity.
- It buffers until reaching *each* end-of-file, making interactive/sparse filename-entering unusable.

Problems with your `tail -f output` usage:

- It waits for end-of-file at first.
- Once end-of-file is *first* reached (your script got killed the first time), it would give only 10 last lines of the script output so far; breaking operational integrity.

(Buffering is not a problem at `tail -f output` since its output leg is a terminal)

See *Conclusion* below for remedies.

#### Long Explanation

The job description of `tail` is essentially: "*output 10 lines that is just before **end-of-file***". The `-f` switch only adds "*and everything that got subsequently appended to it*".

- In order to accomplish its main goal, `tail` would have to keep reading the input, silently and endlessly (with only latest 10 lines kept in the buffer), until it got end-of-file. Then it would dump the last 10 lines from buffer to the output, and quit (or continue operating in `-f` phase).

Now, let me remind you that **end-of-file on *pipe* never comes until the upstream program terminates**<sup>1</sup>...

The result is `tail -f output` will, ***by design***, keep silently buffering through your script's result, without emitting anything... until the moment you first terminated your script: an end-of-file got sent to `tail -f output`, that's when you started seeing your output.

- But **what you see is not the whole output** so far, but rather **just the last 10 lines of output** at that point.

  If you asked your script to analyze 20 files (with less than 10 files at a time, see next point), you would get only the result of last 10 files analyzed just before you killed the script the first time. **This breaks the expectation (i.e. integrity) of your script's operation**, where result of *every* analysis done should have been reported on the output.
- This problem also affect `tail -f input`. Dumping a file list with 11+ filenames into your `input` pipe *at first time*, will result in only 10 bottommost names reaching your script, **breaking the integrity of your script's operation** again. On second and later times, this would not be a problem.

And that is not even the end of the story...

Once reached the first end-of-file, `tail -f` would continue operating in `-f` phase, which means *output everything that got subsequently appended to the input file*.

In this phase, it would not close the input handle yet; it will register an [`inotify`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) listener on the input *file*, and wait. Each time that any program writes to/closes the input file, `tail` would read the input handle again (and *output everything it just read*), until it encounters end-of-file<sup>2</sup>, and it will be back to waiting again. Rinse and repeat until you manually terminate `tail -f`.

- A catch here is "*output everything it just read*" **also subjected to usual output buffering** when the output is not terminal.

  It does not affect your use of `tail -f output` per se (as its output leg is a terminal). `tail -f input` however, will be affected:

  - If you entered multiple filenames interactively with `cat > input` , you would see that processing won't start until you terminate `cat`.
  - And this means connecting `input` pipe to a long-running program that only occasionally emit filenames, won't work either.

#### Conclusion

In my understanding, you used `tail -f input` to shield your script from receiving end-of-file, so your script could keep running like a [daemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29), while filename-giver programs could just come and go.

So my advice is to use `tail -n +1 -f` instead, to make sure that `tail` don't go on endless hunts for end-of-file, and eliminate the last-10-line problem. Then use `stdbuf` to control buffering where it would be an issue<sup>3,4</sup>...

```
stdbuf -oL tail -n +1 -f input | ../entropyCalc/entropy.py > output 2>&1
```

Then on the monitoring side, use either:

```
tail -n +1 -f output
```

or:

```
while true; do cat output; done
```

#### Footnotes

- <sup>1</sup> Or more precisely, when the upstream program closes the pipe. (In your case, it would only happen to `tail -f output` when your script terminates)
- <sup>2</sup> Never happens to your `tail -f output`, unless you terminated your script the *second* time.
- <sup>3</sup> Your script is already line-buffered on its output stage, so no need for `stdbuf` there.
- <sup>4</sup> A standard error redirection `2>&1` will also ensure that script error also displays on the monitoring terminal.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood why you wrote that `tail -f` waits for EOF, a simple test for this is following: Step 1: create named fifo; `mkfifo test`. Step 2: Use `tail -f` to listen on the contents; `tail -f test` Step 3: Write something to the fifo without feedin it EOF; `cat > test`. Now, `tail -f` won't buffer or lose the data even if you don't write 10 lines or don't provide EOF. You can see your input being printed by tail -f immediately without any buffering.

Comment: @lol, **negative**. I did the exact simple test steps you mentioned: **`tail -f` didn't display a thing**- [screenshot A](https://u.cubeupload.com/xwindows/moHgHX.png), [screenshot B](https://u.cubeupload.com/xwindows/anb3EJ.png). After several minutes of silence, I ended `cat > test` with _Ctrl+D_; and last 10 lines instantly appeared on `tail -f` output, just like what I described- [screenshot C](https://u.cubeupload.com/xwindows/9E0n2M.png). GNU Coreutils 8.13 `tail`, Linux kernel 3.2.65.

Comment: @lol, anyway, did you try the commands given in _Conclusion_ yet? **Did they somehow _not work_ in your configuration?** (They _did work_ on mine, so any elaboration on how exactly they went wrong on yours would be useful)

Comment: This is very weird, so I tried the exact same thing as I mentioned in my first comment. `tail -f` at least on my machine buffers everything until it receives the first EOF after that it's line buffered. I'm using GNU coreutils 8.28 on Linux 5.0.0.