# docker-compose, less and SIGINT

Tags: bash, docker, less, trap, sigint

I have a script that boots up a test environment using `docker-compose`.
This script pipes the mixed stdout of many docker containers on stdout through less:

```bash
# This is part of a larger script with some setup and teardown.
$ docker-compose up --build | less +F -r
```

`less` shows an undesired behavior here: When hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, `docker-compose` receives it and shuts down itself. Desired behaviour is only to interrupt the following (`+F`) feature of `less` (like it does when viewing e.g. a large log).

**What I want to achieve in the optimal case:
Interrupt the following with the first <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and quit the whole test environment on the second <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.**

I've toyed a bit around and tried the following things:

- Register a `trap 'do_exit' SIGINT` that would implement the logic above. `docker-compose` however still exited upon <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.
- Use `trap '' SIGINT` to catch SIGNT totally. `docker-compose` however still got the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> out of thin air.

*Another observation:*

This works in `zsh`: `(trap '' SIGINT && docker-compose up --build | less +F -r)` (it does not react to SIGINT at all)
The same line behaves differently in bash and is killed by SIGINT.

Here is the full (buggy) script for reference:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

service_name=xxx

for dir in ../1 ../2 ../3; do
    if [ ! -d "$dir" ]; then
      echo "docker compose requires $dir, please check $dir do exist in the same folder level"
      exit 0
    fi
done

docker-compose up --build | less +F -r

if [ ! $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Couldn't start service or Control-C was pressed"
    echo "cleaning up"
    docker-compose down
    exit $?
fi

docker-compose rm --all --force
```

Any solution or experiences with this?

--

Edit: I've also tried the solutions here without any success:

- [Is there any way to exit “less” follow mode without stopping other processes in pipe?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197199/is-there-any-way-to-exit-less-follow-mode-without-stopping-other-processes-in)
- [Follow a pipe using less?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26826/follow-a-pipe-using-less/139295#139295)

Comment: `pkill -INT less` from another terminal?

Comment: Thanks @muru, ``pkill -INT less`` kind of works (only kills less, but not docker-compose), but doesn't really answer the question. Preferably I want to be able to hit Ctrl-C directly in the terminal out of convinience (and I also want to understand how this works...)

Comment: Have you tried `(trap '' INT && docker-compose up --build) | less +F -R`?

Comment: Note that your script will also get the SIGINT

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Thanks. Still pressing ``CTRL-C`` will stop ``docker-compose``, while it should only stop  the paging mode of ``less``. Can you explain why ``(docker-compose up --build | less +F -r)`` is not interruptable in ``zsh`` and but is in ``bash``?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after reading this:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group
- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control.html#Job-Control

The solution is to do `set -m` at the start of the script.
This causes bash to create a new process group for each process,
not causing SIGINT to be send to every process in the script.

For reference, the fixed script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -m
set -e

service_name=xxx

for dir in ../1 ../2 ../3; do
    if [ ! -d "$dir" ]; then
      echo "docker compose requires $dir, please check $dir do exist in the same folder level"
      exit 0
    fi
done

TEMP_LOG_FILE=$(mktemp --suffix '-dev-env-log')
(trap '' SIGINT && docker-compose up --build > ${TEMP_LOG_FILE}) &
less +F -r ${TEMP_LOG_FILE}
rm ${TEMP_LOG_FILE}

echo "Less was quit, stopping containers..."


if [ ! $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "could not start service or Control-C was pressed"
    echo "cleaning up"
    docker-compose down
    exit $?
fi

docker-compose down
docker-compose rm --all --force
```

Comment: _This causes bash to create a new process group for each process, not causing SIGINT to be send to every process in the script._ – then why do you still need a trap for SIGINT when running `docker-compose`?