# Find and delete Syntax

Tags: find

I have a hard drive that contains about 300,000 x 3 files that were written by a recovery program.

Some of these files are in the format:

```
.doc.apple.quarantine
```

These are easy to remove:

```
find . -type f -name '*.apple.quarantine' -delete
```

But others are more difficult because they have the phrase

`_AFP_Afpinfo` which may have been written after the file extension, e.g.

```
happybirthday.mp3._AFP_afpinfo
```

or just

```
happybirthday_AFP_Afpinfo
```

I would like to delete the third type of file, i.e.:

```
happybirthday_AFP_Afpinfo
```

so my question is whether this Unix command will delete all files that contain the characters `AFP_Afpinfo`?

```
find . -type -f 'AFP_Afpinfo' -delete
```

I tested

```
-find . -type -f -name 'epub' -print
```

and no files displayed.

I tried

```
-find -type -f -name 'epub' -print
```

and files displayed. So the use of the period after `find` was incorrect.

After running 1/2 hour or so, running:

```
find -type f -name '_AFP_Afpinfo'
```

the following error was displayed:

```
find: './.Trash-1000/files': Input/output error
```

I checked that directory and it's full of `AFP_Afpinfo` files.

Comment: A good practice is to always run the `find` command without the `-delete` beforehand and see what files show up in the run (pipe to `less` if the list is big).

Comment: | less +F? Could you suggest a proper syntax for less? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197199/is-there-any-way-to-exit-less-follow-mode-without-stopping-other-processes-in

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. I meant run something like `find . -type f -name EXPRESSION -print` which just prints the name of the files, and if the list of files is long you can pipe it to `less` and review if you are finding any files you should not be finding and adjust your expression accordingly.

Comment: The issue is having to shut down the process. It takes forever; the GUI run caused the loss of trash functionality, no more space on the root file system and I don't know what else.

Comment: So you want to find files whose names end in `_AFP_Afpinfo` but only where it is not preceded by a period? if so, you can use `-name '*[^.]_AFP_Afpinfo'` or if you prefer `\( -name '*_AFP_Afpinfo' ! -name '*._AFP_Afpinfo' \)`

Comment: @steeldriver make this into an answer, please.

Comment: @user26732 done - thanks for the feedback

Comment: @user26732: When somebody asks you what your question means, please [edit] your it to make it clearer and more complete.  We like questions and answers that are useful to other people in the future; that requires them to be understandable.  Right now your question is very hard to understand.  Are you using "doc" and "docname" interchangeably?  I guess you are using "doc" and "docname" as a placeholder for a name like ``Dec12`` or `violet` — am I right?  That's not clear. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  And you say "Some of these files are in the format: ``.doc.apple.quarantine`` ... But others are more difficult because they have the phrase "_AFP_Afpinfo" which may have been written after the dot..."  Which dot?  Does that mean `._AFP_Afpinfodoc.apple.quarantine`, `.doc._AFP_Afpinfoapple.quarantine` or `.doc.apple._AFP_Afpinfoquarantine`?  Etc.

Comment: There are three types of files that were created by the recovery program and littered throughout the drive:

Comment: There are three types of files that were created by the recovery program and littered throughout the drive:1. "_AFP_Afpinfo" 2. ".apple.quarantine" 3. "_Mac_Metadata" So, let's say I have a file "001.doc" On the hard drive, this file will spawn four files: 1. A perfectly readable 001.doc. 2. 001.doc_AFP_Afpinfo, 3. 001.doc.apple.quarantine 4. 001.doc_Mac_Metadata  In my question, doc refers to Word files.

Comment: I edited the question, hopefully it is more clear now.

Comment: @ojs, technically `-delete` should be replaced with `-depth -print`, since `-delete` implies `-depth` whether you want it or not. (As a result I have found there are occasions with complex filters where `-exec rm -f {} +` is necessary instead of `-delete`, for example with `-name … -prune`)

Comment: @roaima What does -depth do? Does it need a flag? Or -prune for that matter.

Comment: `man find` and search for `-depth`

Comment: RTFM is always a solution. You suggested -depth, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find . -type -f 'AFP_Afpinfo' -delete` is not correct, or even valid - the `AFP_Afpinfo` would need to be preceded by either `-name` or `-iname`, and would then match files whose whole name matched exactly `AFP_Afpinfo` (case-insensitively, in the case of `-iname`).

If you want to find files whose names end in `_AFP_Afpinfo` but only where it is not preceded by a period, you can do so either as

```
find -type f -name '*[^.]_AFP_Afpinfo'
```

where `[^.]` means any character except `.` or using

```
find -type f \( -name '*_AFP_Afpinfo' ! -name '*._AFP_Afpinfo' \)
```

They are not exactly equivalent - the latter expression would match `_AFP_Afpinfo` whereas the former requires at least one non-period character before the string.

In either case, I **strongly** advise testing with `-print` first in place of `-delete`.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not.

## Tips:

### test it

Try it with with `-print` in place of `-delete`.

### `.` in file name is not special

The `.` is not special: it is just a regular character.
In DOS and CP/M it is special, but you are not using these.
In MS-Windows CMD globs ending in `.*` are special:

- `n.*` does `n`
- so `n.*.*` does `n.*`, and `*.*.*` does `*.*`
- this all comes from the CP/M / DOS legacy, where `*.*` meant all files (all files had a `.` in them.
- this culture is still about, and a lot of folk think that the `.` is special on Unix. It is not, it is just a character (except if it is the first character of a file-name).