# Monitor/follow CSV file changes/updates in a tabular view/format

Tags: command-line, csv, tail

I want to monitor/follow changes of a CSV file (some logging output of a robot). It is a huge file with `<TAB>` as delimiter and the first row with header information.

So far, I am using the output of `tail - f <file.csv>`, but it is not formatted per column, and looks like:

```
yAccelRaw       zAccelRaw       xGyroRaw    ... ... ...
3       256     1   ... ... ...
4       255     3   ... ... ... 
4       255     -6  ... ... ...
3       253     -1  ... ... ...
4       254     2   ... ... ...
5       255     0   ... ... ...
4       255     3   ... ... ...
5       254     3   ... ... ...
5       253     -1  ... ... ...
4       255     3   ... ... ...
```

With a CSV with 30 or more columns, understanding which value belongs to which column is not really easy. I was wandering if there is a **general** solution for printing the output formatted as table?

So far, I use `tail -f <file.csv> | cut -f5,6` to cut out specific columns and observe their output, but I would prefer the full overview. Also, I tried piping the result to `column` which doesn't get updated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use, for example, awk to capture the headers on the first line, and repeat them every 10 lines, and reduce the column size to say max 5 characters  with something like this:

```
tail -n +1 -f file.csv |
awk  'NR==1 { n=split($0,hdr) }
NR%10==1    { for(i=1;i<=n;i++)printf "%5.5s ",hdr[i];printf "\n" }
            { for(i=1;i<=n;i++)printf "%5.5s ",$i;printf "\n" }
'
```

This would give something like

```
yAcce zAcce xGyro ...
    3   256     1 ...
    4   255     3 ... 
    4   255    -6 ...
    3   253    -1 ...
    4   254     2 ...
    5   255     0 ...
    4   255     3 ...
    5   254     3 ...
    5   253    -1 ...
    4   255     3 ...
yAcce zAcce xGyro ...
    3   256     1 ...
...
```

If the width is still too wide to fit in your terminal, you can pipe the result into `less -S +F` which makes it act like `tail -f`, but allows you to scroll left and right with the arrows if you pause the tail with Control-C.  To continue tailing type `F`.

Comment: It helps a lot! Extra points for the header repetition :) However, can you expand on the `less -S -F` idea? I cannot scroll when piping the result to less. Also, the header gets eaten.

Comment: It is `+F` not `-F`. It makes less do a `tail -f` initially. You cannot scroll at this point. You have to interrupt with control-c to stop the tailing, but you stay inside less. you can then scroll: check your keybindings in less if you cannot. When you have the view of the columns you want you can type F again to continue tailing with these columns.

Comment: If I pause `less`, then scroll, and try to continue, `less` is "Waiting for data... (interrupt to abort)" indefinetly. My work around is piping to less without `+F`, scroll and then initiate following with `shift+F` (that also is non-pausable of course in terms of "continue following after pausing"). I assume there is an issue with following a piped input.

Comment: There will be a problem when piping a command into `less` because the control-c can also be delivered to the command as a signal which will probably stop it.  The simplest answer is to put the result in a file and use `less` on that file, so that a control-c will only be received by `less`. Or you can pipe from a shell script if you get it to ignore signals with `trap '' int`. You will have difficulty stopping the script: a useful trick is to use control-z to put it in the background then use a kill command, or use the quit signal (control-\\).

Comment: I found a similar answer in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26826/follow-a-pipe-using-less#139295 ... anyhow, doesn't it make the last part of your answer a bit misleading?

Answer (score 0):

Column does exactly what you're asking for. You can identify tab as the separator with an argument. Why is piping to column not an option here? `cat <file.csv> | column -s "\t"`

Comment: It's not an option because I want to monitor file changes. I know column for that task, but, as far as I know, I have to take care of updating the file input.