# Search with less

Tags: wget, search, less

In the output of `wget --help` I would like to quickly go to the place where the `--header` option is explained.

[image]

I try searching with `less`. `man less` explains:

```
/pattern
              Search  forward  in  the  file  for the N-th line containing the pattern.  N defaults to 1.  The pattern is a regular expression, as recognized by the regular
              expression library supplied by your system.  The search starts at the first line displayed (but see the -a and -j options, which change this).
```

Following this recommendation I try:

```
wget --help | less /header
```

but it causes an error:

```
/header: No such file or directory
```

What is wrong?

Comment: `man less | less -p 'pattern'`

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26826/follow-a-pipe-using-less

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `less` utility will try to open the file(s) listed as operands on the command line.  There is no file called `/header` on your system.  What you tried to do was to give the interactive command for searching for the string `header`, but this can't be done that way from the command line.

Any interactive `less` command can be given as an initial command for `less` to execute by prefixing it with `+` on the command line.  So you could have done

```bsh
wget --help | less '+/header'
```

See `man less | less '+/ \+ '` for more info about that.

This happens to be equivalent to the other way of specifying a search pattern on the command line, `-p pattern`, but is more generic as adding an initial `+` applies to all interactive commands, while `-p` is specifically for specifying a search term.

```bsh
wget --help | less -p 'header'
```

Answer (score 3):

The `/pattern` command is used when you are inside `less`. To use that as a command line switch, use the `-ppattern` option. In this case, `wget --help | less -pheader`.